# Limit a PHP variable (number) to 100

Tags: php

I have a PHP function which returns a number, and I want to display it as a percentage from 1 - 100. Anything over 100 should just be reevaluated to 100. How can I do that?

```
$myvar = 120;
$my_percentage = <$myvar, max value is 100>
```

I'm using Laravel, if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Just check if $myvar is greater than 100 and show $myvar if false else show 100

Comment: @Sigma please don't use the comment section for answers.

Comment: MeaCulpa @Brian H. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the simplest way for restricting the number

```
$my_percentage = min(100, $myvar);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to ensure the value is always less than or equal to 100, then take the minimum (using [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)) of the value and 100...

```
$my_percentage = min(100, $myvar);
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest would be to just use a ternary operator.

```
$myvar = 120;
$my_percentage = $myvar > 100 ? 100 : $myvar;
```

So that in case `$myvar` is bigger than 100 it will just assign 100 to `$my_percentage`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a few ways todo this, just quick without context this is my first thought.

```
$my_precentage = ($myvar < 100) ? $myvar : 100;
```